# How to use non-localised OperationName values in Get-AzLog

Tags: azure, powershell

We use the PowerShell command Get-AzLog to extract event information from Azure. Our code used to work fine, but at some point it seems to have stopped finding the events we want and now returns nothing.  It appears the non-localised versions of the OperationName are no longer available, and we are now forced to use the localised version instead.  Can anyone confirm if this is correct? Or are we doing something wrong in our original code?

Code that used to work:

```
Get-AzLog | Where-Object {$_.OperationName.value -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/delete"}
```

Code that works now, but unfortunately uses the localised strings instead of the canonical values:

```
Get-AzLog | Where-Object {$_.OperationName -eq "Delete SQL database"}
```

When I look in the Azure portal, the Activity Log shows that the data I need is there -- I just can't seem to get the syntax right to filter on it:
[image: Screenshot of the data available in Azure portal]

I've tried various different methods of accessing the nested property, but none seem to work -- the only version of "OperationName" that I can access is the localised version.

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears the non-localised versions of the OperationName are no longer available, and we are now forced to use the localised version instead.

Yes, you are correct, the non-localized versions of OperationName are no longer Available.

I have executed below command and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azlog?view=azps-0.10.0):

```
Get-AzLog
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

You can clearly see that OperationName only contains Localized value.
So you need to change your code as azure commands and its outputs keeps updating.